# Topics by SciFi Author, can or should we define some as in and some as out of scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I would guess that probably all of use can think of and agree on at least half dozen Science Fiction authors who's work shaped space exploration as it is today.

We can probably also agree on several who's literary contributions while fun to read do/did little to shape, impact or reflect scientific inquiry.

There is of course a bunch of grey in the middle...

Do we want to preemptively list authors who's work may be appropriate for discussion here, and those who works are not?

Answer (score 9):

No, I'm personally against defining reasons for what is or isn't within the scope of our Q&A based on popular literature, their respective authors, or popularity of the topics they wrote about within their popular literature titles, because that might in itself imply greater credibility of such sources and their respective authors than it might be sometimes warranted.

Yes, some Sci-Fi authors were great visionaries, and some have even been actively involved in space exploration progress, but that they were also authors of popular fiction literature titles is, in my view, beyond the point.

I just don't see it as an issue that warrants putting our gloves on, not on its own at least.